# How to make full screen zoom feature with scrolling multiple images with TNImageSliderViewController?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I am losing most of my work time stucking at scrollview,autolayout issues.And now,when i found TNImageSliderViewController.I see that i have hope in scrolling images with no autolayout issue.Thanks to the developer who write [TNImageSliderViewController](https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNImageSliderViewController).But,after that I want to do another thing which still keep making me stuck.I tried many tutorial and video and which keep making me stuck.

Here is what i need to do...

1.When I clicked one of my image in scrollview,i want to see full screen of that images i click at another view.

2.That another view should also have capabilities like TNImageSliderViewController which we can slide images.

3.I want to add zoom with pinch or tapped zoom at full screen image that i clicked.

Any Idea?or suggestion or library which it can do it easily and completely with no autolayout issue which we can rotate as we like?

Please help...Please,I really need help.Also all newbie like us might want the same answer like me.